# How can I quickly tell which ARM Thumb version a particular piece of code is using?

Tags: disassembly, binary-analysis, arm, binary-format, thumb2

I'm working with an ARM processor: an STM32F407VGT6 board, which IIUC powers a 32-bit Arm® Cortex®-M4. I need to inspect the binary weight of some instruction, so I used `objdump` like this:

```
arm-none-eabi-objdump -b binary --adjust-vma=0x08000000 --start-address=0x08000002 \
  -marm --disassembler-options=force-thumb -D binary_program.bin > /tmp/binary_program-bin.s
```

First, I tested a loop of instructions like this:

```
adds    r0, r0, #255
```

and I got in the `.s` file

```
 80002e4:   30ff        adds    r0, #255    ; 0xff
```

After a **long** search in [the ARM manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0487/latest) (and I hope I found the correct one), I could map that binary as:

```
instruction: 001_10_000_11111111
bit mask:    111_11_198_76543210
             543_21_0
```

where

- `111` = "Add, subtract, compare, move (one low register and immediate)", page F3-7301
- `10` = "ADD, ADDS (immediate)", version T2 is at page F5-7453
- `000` = `r0`, source and destination register
- `11111111` = 255, the immediate operand

This, IIUC, is **Thumb-2**. So far so good, but the problem is that other instructions, which are not representable with Thumb-2, get mapped to **Thumb-3**, like

```
adds    r0, r0, #256
```

which becomes

```
 80002e4:   f510 7080   adds.w  r0, r0, #256    ; 0x100
```

Obviously this is no more T2, and the bit encoding should be something like

```
      i 0 op1  S Rn   0 imm3 Rd   imm8
11110_1_0_1000_1_0000_0_111__0000_10000000
33222_2_2_2222_2_1111_1_111__1198_76543210
10987_6_5_4321_0_9876_5_432__10
```

as reported at "Data-processing (modified immediate)", pages F3-7310 and F3-7311. This lead me to pages F5-7452 to 55, "ADD, ADDS (immediate)".
Searching a lot, I found it should be T3: the mnemonic matches (`adds.w`). This would mean the processor expands the bits `11:0` like this:

1. it concatenates a `1` with the bits `6:0`, `1 0000000`
2. extends with `0`s to get a 32 bit word: `00000000000000000000000010000000`
3. it rotates right the integer of the amount specified in bits `11:7`, which is `11111`, or 31, getting `00000000000000000000000100000000 = 256`.

The point is, since I'm using the same compiler for both the codes, and they end up to use different ISAs to translate the instructions, **how can I tell which one is which**, without dwelling the depths of the ARM manual every time?

Thanks!